# Can I set the property spring.cloud.function.definition programmatically?

Tags: java, spring, properties, stream, cloud

I use Spring Cloud streams for Kafka and set properties like this:

```
spring.cloud:
    stream:
        function.definition: method1;method2;...
```

Can I set the property "spring.cloud.stream.function.definition" (or "spring.cloud.function.definition" which is the same) in java code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution:

```
StreamFunctionProperties streamFunctionProperties;
....
streamFunctionProperties.setDefinition("method1;method2");
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your solution please?